# How to steal output of any command ran on linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am using bash/zsh. I want to steal output of any command ran on the shell terminal and colorify it, then display on the terminal.

```
[user@machine]$ my-command-to-exe-tests --run-all-tcs
bunch of output
bunch of output
bunch of output
bunch of output
[user@machine]$
```

Is there a way to do this without using pipe |. Like whatever output is displayed on terminal must go through my program. Is it possible to hook pts or tty to steal output stream of any command ran on terminal?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117054/can-zsh-access-the-stdout-of-last-run-program), in particular to the answer given by Mikel. The comments also explain where this approach breaks down, but I guess this is the closest you can get (unless you are prepared to modify the code for your terminal program).

Comment: Should the coloring happen in some meaningful way or would you just like to uniformly color all output? In the latter case, why not just change the color theme in your terminal emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with randomly colorizing then you can use lolcat tool to do the task.

```
$ lolcat <(your command)
```

Comment: I guess the OP considers process substitution as a thing to be avoided in the same way as using a pipe, so this would `lolcat` as well. Since every command which produces output on the terminal should be displayed in funny colours, I guess we would have to write a special version of either the terminal (rxvt,...) or the shell (zsh,....).